# Is it possible to make part of the text inside EditText one color and the other part another color?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Is it possible to make part of the text inside **EditText** one color and the other part another color?

Comment: use two `editText`

Comment: This is a very good solution , works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example working with Html, but you can easily change it

```
    String text = "<p>Hello world</p>";

    // create Spanned
    Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(text);
    // create SpannableString
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(spanned);

    // set colored part
    ClickableSpan coloredPart = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            ds.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    };

spanString.setSpan(coloredPart, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

editText.setText(spanString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure no problem.

```
TextAppearanceSpan mHighlightTextSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(mContext, R.style.searchTextHighlight);

int startOfTextSearchTeam = orderModel.getTitle() != null ? indexOfSearchTermFromName(orderModel.getTitle()) : -1; //simple search for string in string for index

    final SpannableString highlightTitle = new SpannableString(orderModel.getTitle() + " " + mContext.getString(R.string.count_open_bracket) + orderModel.getImageCount() + mContext.getString(R.string.count_closed_bracket));

    // Sets the span to start at the starting point of the match and end at "length"
    // characters beyond the starting point
    if(startOfTextSearchTeam != -1){
        highlightTitle.setSpan(mHighlightTextSpan, startOfTextSearchTeam, startOfTextSearchTeam + mSearchTerm.length(), 0);
        itemViewHolder.txtOrderTitle.setText(highlightTitle);

    }
```

I do this inside a recycler view adapter as I'm highlighting spans on each row as they search, but it's identical concept. Also I knew up the highlightTextSpan only one time in the constructor.

Hope that helps. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpannableString`, try this.

```
    SpannableString spannableText = new SpannableString("Text default to color");
    final EditText diffColor = new EditText(getActivity());
    // make "Text" (characters 0 to 4) red

    spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 4, 0);
    diffColor.setText(spannableText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. It will work...

```
    EditText edtText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtText);
    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello world in android");
    final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
   // code to specify the character which do you want to change color. In this I have set value from 0,4 to change the color of firts 4 character from string.
    sb.setSpan(fcs,0,4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    edtText.setText(sb);
```